# How does maven find out what is the files changed by using mvn compile

Tags: java, maven

If I don't use `maven clean`, maven compiles only modified files.
I was googling and I also tried to find in "target" folder information such as hashcode of class or date
but couldn't.
How does maven find out what is the files modified by using `mvn compile`?

Comment: The filesystem on your computer keeps track of when a file was last changed. Maven compares the last change time of the source file with the corresponding class file. If the source file is newer than the class file, it recompiles the source file into a new class file.

Comment: You can look for <staleMillis> at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html

Comment: @jesper where in the comiled file this date is saved?  I didn't find information in "target" folder. for example I created two classes in one hour run compile, than in one hour change one of two classes. how manen find out what is the files is modified

Comment: It's in the metadata of the file system; it's not stored in a file. On Linux when you use the command `ls -l` or on Windows using `dir` you'll see the date and time that a file was last modified.